# Perl line by line tracing activate / deactivate per file

Tags: perl, trace

I have lot of Perl code lines to fix bugs, Perl is closed book for me.

I am looking to trace the code flow using following strategy in shebang:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -d:Trace
```

> ~$ ./trialPerlTracing.pl
>   >> ./trialPerlTracing.pl:12: print "Statement 1 at line 4\n"; Statement 1 at line 4
>   >> ./trialPerlTracing.pl:13: print "Statement 2 at line 5\n"; Statement 2 at line 5
>   >> ./trialPerlTracing.pl:14: print "Call to sub x returns ", &x(), " at line 6.\n";
>   >> ./trialPerlTracing.pl:20:   print "In sub x at line 12.\n"; In sub x at line 12.
>   >> ./trialPerlTracing.pl:21:   return 13; Call to sub x returns 13 at line 6.
>   >> ./trialPerlTracing.pl:16: exit 0;

This same strategy did NOT work in the actual software I was trying to trace.

I guess somewhere, they have redirected stdout/stderr, how do I redirect to file of my choice selectively?

Comment: When something is said to be "an open book",  it means it's "easily understood". Is that really what you meant?

Comment: In what way did it not work? If you only provide information about the scenario in which it does work, then there's no way for us to help you.

Comment: @ikegami, I actually meant the opposite of it, I have edited it. I have no knowledge of PERL for now.
I have inserted the same shebang in xxx_yyy.pm (a perl module), then it does NOT work ... I found other statements in it like yyy__Log::Trace("Failed - $ret_status->{erorText}") these are visible on the console.

Comment: These perl modules are invoked from BASH script that call other PERL scripts, running a perl script separately at command prompt would not make sense, we require to trace it from within such environment created by other BASH, PYTHON, PERL scripts.

Answer (score 1):

Since those *shebang* lines are just comments to Perl, they work only in main Perl programs, not in Perl modules, so you'd have to insert them into the main Perl scripts or run the programs with `perl -d:Trace path_to_script`.